# How Unity resolves Func<type, type>

Tags: c#, unity-container

Can anybody help me resolve the following line through Unity 2.0?

```
var instance = 
      new Class1(new Func<int, ReadOnlyCollection<Entity1> >(
                   (e) => new Entity1().GetAll()
                )
      );
```

Thanks,
Moiz

Comment: This question doesn't make sense. Are you saying that you want to create an instance of `Class1` via Unity?

Comment: Could you please tell us more, what you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you mean?:

```
IUnityContainer container = ...;

container.RegisterInstance<Func<int, ReadOnlyCollection<Entity1>>(e => new Entity1().GetAll()));
container.RegisterType<Class1>();

var instance = container.Resolve<Class1>();
```

Comment: Thanks OJ. Would you mind to help me write the same code in unity.config file.